# What should not be included in Australian resume?

Tags: resume, professionalism, australia

I've learned that in Australia, similarly to UK and Canada it's considered faux-pas to include some personal information in the resume.

- date of birth
- nationality
- photo
- exact address
- something else?

Which personal but possibly relevant details should be left off of a resume besides those I have already listed and how would I determine if the detail is appropriate?

Comment: Where did you learn it was faux-pas? Does it not say there what isn't allowed? Googling about this does't seem to bring up any results at all that say it should be any different than any other resume.

Comment: Since this had the potential to turn into a list question I have updated it to ask how to determine if the detail is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

When in school in Australia, we had lessons from a [Career Advice Company](http://insideoutcoach.com.au/) in creating the ideal Resume tailored to the Australian Job Market. The “Contact Details” section in which you must clearly indicate your full name, phone number, e-mail, and the type of Visa you currently possess (Working Holiday, De Facto, etc..). You can also add your nationality but you don’t have to indicate your date of birth. You should not include a photograph unless you are told to do so.

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to have a source that backs this up do you? I appreciate that its from when you were in school and might not have a source other than that, but i feel the answer would be improved greatly with evidence from a reputable source.

Comment: @RhysW Good point thank you. I have added in the link to the company that provided the advice session.

Answer (score 2):

Generally these could be clues to the employer that might permit discrimination, such as age or race or implicit religion or ethnicity.  Your resume should only focus on skills and experience.

When I was first in the job market in the 1970s people commonly indicated that they were married, if they were, which would hint at stability. These days, it might hint that you're going to be feeding at the benefits trough for an unemployed spouse and minor children.

When one is looking for work in the US, it is important that one be 'local'.  I suspect the same is true in Australia. One often finds 'No sponsorship or telecommuting is offered at this time' included in ads.

If you are going through a recruiter, the recruiter will white out your address before forwarding the resume to the hiring manager.

Comment: I agree with parts of this, (read: paragraph one). but paragraph three is related to a completely different country and paragraph 4 seems to be a massive over generalization, i don't imagine every recruiter behaves exactly in that way.

Comment: @RhysW - Actually recruiters generally submit candidates with out an personal contact information since they want to make sure any contact goes through them and they avoid the potential for losing the candidate to direct hire where the recruiter is cut out.  I also updated paragraph three to include what I read as an unspoken understanding that it is this way in the US and it is reasonable to expect something similar in Australia.  It is probably different in the EU but its hard to commute from Washington to Sidney everyday.

Answer (score 2):

As an Australian who has worked in the US, UK and of course Oz, I can honestly say that i'm not aware of this - but i work in IT, perhaps your industry is different, whatever it might be.

Aside from the "experience" bit (and the address, of course), my CV has been the same for the past 10 years.

I've *always* had all the items you've listed as "faux pas worthy" (well, aside from the "something else" section), and as an added guide I'd advise you to put whatever visa you hold that makes you eligible for work in Australia on your CV too.

Unless you do not have one, then just leave it out (and your nationality too).

Your photo isn't expected (in IT) but might be in other industries. Otherwise I've never had any issue with different countries and their CV ettiquete.

Of course, if in doubt, lob it to a random recruiter and get their opinion.